# Qt framework OK for this Windows and Mac GUI?

Tags: c++, qt

Some background. I'm writing a program that needs to monitor the default audio buffer and write to a virtual COM port. Both those operations are platform specific, and are driven via an GUI.

My question is, would the Qt framework suffice? I'm heard great things about it on my never ending google quest, but I am not sure how well it handles platform-specific code. In theory, I would just need to abstract two platform-specific classes. The rest of the program would be cross-platform compliant, written in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Qt is definitely useful for the GUI. However depending on if Qt offers the ability to access the audio buffer and virtual COM port you may have to couple that with the use of [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Boost is also cross-platform like Qt.